# Why must we always read the last element we write with C unions?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I'm reading some slides on `enum`s and `unions`, and one slide says:

> You must always read the last element you write.

And then there's the following code:

```
union Value {
    int int_value; 
    float float_value; 
    char *str_value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    union Value v;
    v.str_value = "hi"; 
    v.int_value = 100;

    printf("v = %s\n", v.str_value); /* undefined behavior! */ 
}
```

What does it mean that we always have to read the last element we write? Why is accessing the field `str_value` of the union `v` undefined behaviour?

Comment: Was the slide you read online? If yes, can you provide a link to that slide.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ No, it's not an online slide, and I'm not sure I can share it with you...

Comment: ^^ Oh, I understand. It is confidential. No problems. I was just asking because sometimes there is more information in the slide. But are you sure that is the only line related to that topic? There might be some line up or down giving some hint.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ There's nothing more...

Comment: I think what they're trying to say is that it's up to you, the programmer, to keep track of what you put in the union. Obviously the 100 assignment clobbers the "hi" pointer value that was there before.

Comment: Reading a member of a union other than the one last written to is not undefined behavior, but implementation-defined. However, passing a `char *` that does not point to a valid string to `printf()` *is* undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF So, my question is, why `v.str_value` is not a valid char?

Comment: @nbro: That is the wrong question to ask. The question is, why *should* it be a valid `char*`?

Comment: @EOF I don't think there are wrong questions, but at most wrong answers. I think that this problem has raised for me because I've not understood exactly what are these unions and how they are implemented under the hood..

Comment: @nbro: C11 draft standard n1570, `6.2.5 Types, 20 Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as
follows: [...]— A union type describes an overlapping nonempty set of member objects, each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.` Note the "overlapping".

Comment: @EOF So, basically, as also Mr. Branch is saying in it's answer below, the `union` `Value` will occupy only the size of the biggest variable that it contains; in this case, it may be the `float` or `int`. <cont>

Comment: <cont> So, let me try to answer to my own question. Since we're assigning a value `100` to the attribute `int_value`, the previous value assigned to `str_value` will be basically overwritten, so trying to access it will be undefined behaviour, because its contents are no more what we think we put there previously. But how are these unions implemented under the hood in memory? It would be nice to know then...

Comment: No, accessing a member of a union other than the one last written to is **not undefined behavior**. Did you even read my erlier comment to that effect?

Comment: @EOF Yes, it's implementation defined, but in practice it means that's undefined behaviour because I've no time to read the implementation of the compiler.

Comment: @nbro: You obviously don't understand the meaning of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @EOF I understood perfectly the meaning of undefined behaviour, it basically means that it's not guaranteed anything, i.e. anything could happen. You're saying that it's implementation defined, and I believe you, but I've not time to read the documentation or the implementation of my compiler, so I will just assume it's undefined behaviour, in other words, I won't access any field of a union other than the last one written. And my comment before was a joke of course :)

Comment: @nbro: Did you know that converting a value to a signed type is implementation-defined behavior if the value cannot be represented by the type? Are you *quite sure* you never do this? Implementation-defined behavior is ubiquitous, and generally pretty harmless.

Comment: @EOF please point out in the standard does it state that there is a certain behaviour to accessing the other member of the union.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala C11 draft standard n1570 `6.5.2.3 Structure and union members 95) If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.`.

Comment: @EOF thanks, tried to find it but the pdf is so hard to read.

Comment: @EOF: Unfortunately, the effect of taking the address of a union member and accessing the object identified thereby is not clearly defined by the Standard; while taking the address of a union member should yield a pointer to the object identified thereby, which could then be used to access that member, that doesn't always work in modern compilers even in cases where all members of a union are structures which share a common initial sequence, and the pointer is only used to access things within that common initial sequence.

Comment: @supercat How does that relate to anything I've written?

Answer (score 1):

The concept behind unions is the following:
It's a "structure" which occupies the size of the biggest(in memory terms) data type included.

```
union myunion
{
    char letter;
    int number;
};
```

The union will occupy the size of 1 int, meaning 4/8 bytes depending on the computer. Meaning that the char and number will be sharing the same space. That means that if you do something like the following:

```
myunion.letter='a';
myunion.number=2000;
```

You will probably step over the rest of the variables in the union . Meaning that when you try to pick up the letter the value will not be 'a' anymore.
It's not undefined behavior only that you're stepping over the rest of the variables (the whole point behind unions), you can actually know what the char value will be based on the distribution of bytes in the union. That's why it's explained to only read the last element you write, as the rest might be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this is that a union (unlike a regular struct) can only hold *one* value at a time since the elements share the same memory space. Your program will need to keep track of which one is valid at any one time.

So when you assign to (or "write") the `int_value` you are overwriting the memory that was also used by `str_value`. The contents of the union now only makes sense as an int; if you try reading it by using `str_value` you will get a nonsensical result. Or in this case even a crash since you're trying to follow a pointer which doesn't point anywhere meaningful.